# Xcode crashes due to 'There can only be one document registered with a given URL.'

Tags: xcode

I am not able to start up XCode. Whenever it starts it just crashes with this error:

```
Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 8E3004b
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-12175.1/IDEKit/Application/IDEDocumentController.m:2136
Details:  There can only be one document registered with a given URL. newDocument:<IDEWorkspaceDocument: 0x7ff6612d6cd0>(  0   -[IDEWorkspaceDocument init] (in IDEKit)
  1   -[NSDocument initForURL:withContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
  2   -[IDEWorkspaceDocument initForURL:withContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEKit)
  3   -[NSDocumentController makeDocumentForURL:withContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
  4   __104-[NSDocumentController makeDocumentForURL:withContentsOfURL:alternateContents:ofType:completionHandler:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
  5   -[NSDocumentController makeDocumentForURL:withContentsOfURL:alternateContents:ofType:completionHandler:] (in AppKit)
  6   __89-[NSDocumentController reopenDocumentForURL:withContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
```

[image]

How can I get Xcode start again?

**EDIT:**

Version of the xcode is 8.3.3

[image]

Comment: Please restart your system ...

Comment: @PalSinghAnand Do you know the root cause of this exception? Just curious and want to understand.

Comment: what version of xcode you are using now?

Comment: @PalSinghAnand 8.3.3

Comment: @PalSinghAnand Still crashed after reboot

Comment: Did you resolve this problem somehow? I'm having the same issue ... :( Found out it doesn't happen for a newly created project.

Comment: @Kukosk think I find the solution

Comment: @AnthonyKong could you share your solution please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this folder

```
/Users/<your user name>/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState
```

Comment: Encountered this issue using Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235) and can confirm that deleting the application's saved state folder worked perfectly.

Comment: Same problem. For me to fix it, the solution was to create new single view application, open the storyboard there, and then I could go back to my original project and it worked fine.

Answer (score 18):

For me, the solution was to remove all custom color pickers in:

```
~/Library/ColorPickers/
```

Comment: This is interesting! Where did they come from?

Comment: @AnthonyKong I must have installed them a long time ago for some reason. I think it was when it wasn't possible to set a color using RGB values.

Comment: My instance of this crash was being triggered by opening a particular storyboard. Deleting the Zeplin color picker in that folder did the trick.

Comment: Thank you for figuring this out!  I tried deleting every other folder I could think of to fix this and none of them worked until this one

Comment: I removed the ZeplinColorPicker.colorPicker file and it worked! 

Comment: Same. ZeplinColorPicker.colorPicker zapped and everything works. Deleting saved state as per above did nothing.